# How to query a decimal with LINQ to Entities?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

This is a simple query, that always throws following exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Decimal' to type 'System.String'.

Code:

```
public ActionResult Search(SearchModel model)
{
    var vendorList = db.Vendors.Where(v => v.IssueAmount == model.IssueAmount)
                               .ToList();            

    if (vendorList != null && vendorList.Count > 1) 
       return View("SearchResults", vendorList);
    else if (vendorList != null && vendorList.Count == 1)
       return View("Details", vendorList[0]);
    else 
        return View();
}
```

`IssueAmount` is a nullable decimal, and if I try this with any of my string fields, it will work.

**Edit:  Thanks for the replies, everyone.  As suspected it was a stupid mistake:  Turns out the validation on one of my models was the thing that was throwing the exception.  I thought this was valid:**

```
    [DisplayName("Issue Amount")]
    [StringLength(13)]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal? IssueAmount { get; set; }
```

**If I remove the StringLength validator, it clicks along fine.**

Comment: Exactly where is this exception happening?

Comment: Sorry but Which line? I think you should point out the line the exception threw at so that we don't have to look at all the lines and analyze.

Comment: IssueAmount is a nullable decimal in both db.Vendors AND SearchModel ?

Comment: That's another thing that has been confusing me.  If I set a break point on the first line of that function, it will just throw the error without ever hitting it - though if I change the query to search by a string, it will execute (hit the break point) and redirect correctly.

Comment: Yes, Ouarzy.  I've triple checked - they're both nullable decimals.

Comment: Damith, I just tried it and it still throws the same exception.

Comment: The exception is likely happening in your view, please check the IssueAmount usages inside it.

Comment: What is the type of `IssueAmount` in the database?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `IssueAmount` in your `SearchModel` class to a `Decimal`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like either `v.IssueAmount` or `model.IssueAmount` is a string. To fix it most likely you need to make `string` one to be `decimal?` too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do your query like this:

```
var vendors = db.Vendors
                .Where(v => v.IssueAmount.HasValue && 
                            v.IssueAmount == model.IssueAmount);
```